# Run multiple instances of C# application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, powershell

I have a WMI Event defined in a Power shell script that keeps monitoring a folder for new files.

As and when a new file appears the power-shell script triggers a C# program.
This is working fine when I have 1 file at a time.

But if I have multiple new files in the same folder then how do I create multiple instances of my application to process those files?

Comment: Why don't you pass the file path to each of the C# programs? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Why i can't edit this post? :)

Comment: @spajce I tried, there's a problem and it's submitted to StackExchange. Don't worry, these things happen.

Comment: @spajce Adding somewhat random italicizing and highlighting to a post doesn't help readability.

Answer (score 0):

Change your c# program to take the folder as an argument.

Process each unprocessed file in the folder the files in the folder. 
Part of the process should do something to the file, such as
rename it (say suffix it with _processed), changed the extension (.processed), or my favourite move it to an other folder.

Way more efficient, than kicking off masses of executables.

Comment: Tony, That is the ideal solution but unfortunately i cannot move the file to a different folder after reading it.

Comment: What about a rename then, otherwise you need to follwo on from @Alireza's comment